# Objective C Boolean Array

Tags: c, objective-c, arrays, boolean, primitive

I need to utilize an array of booleans in objective-c. I've got it mostly set up, but the compiler throws a warning at the following statement:

```
[updated_users replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:YES];
```

This is, I'm sure, because YES is simply not an object; it's a primitive. Regardless, I need to do this, and would greatly appreciate advice on how to accomplish it.

Thanks.

Comment: When asking about a warning please post the warning in question :)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Yep, that's exactly what it is: the NS* containers can only store objective-C objects, not primitive types.

You should be able to accomplish what you want by wrapping it up in an NSNumber:

`[updated_users replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]`

or by using `@(YES)` which wraps a `BOOL` in an `NSNumber`

`[updated_users replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:@(YES)]]`

You can then pull out the boolValue:

`BOOL mine = [[updated_users objectAtIndex:index] boolValue];`

Answer (score 14):

Assuming your array contains valid objects (and is not a c-style array):

```
#define kNSTrue         ((id) kCFBooleanTrue)
#define kNSFalse        ((id) kCFBooleanFalse)
#define NSBool(x)       ((x) ? kNSTrue : kNSFalse)

[updated_users replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:NSBool(YES)];
```

Comment: I'm curious to find out why Nicks answer got so much more support than this one, as this seems more elegant. Can anyone explain the difference?

Answer (score 12):

You can either store `NSNumbers`:

```
[updated_users replaceObjectAtIndex:index
                         withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

or use a C-array, depending on your needs:

```
BOOL array[100];
array[31] = YES;
```

Answer (score 8):

Like Georg said, use a C-array.

```
BOOL myArray[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  myArray[i] = NO;
}

if (myArray[2]){
   //do things;
}
```

Martijn, "myArray" is the name you use, "array" in georg's example.

Answer (score 5):

From XCode 4.4 you can use Objective-C literals.

`[updated_users replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:@YES];`

Where `@YES` is equivalent of `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`

Answer (score 1):

If your collection is large or you want it to be faster than objc objects, try the `CFBitVector`/`CFMutableBitVector` types found in CoreFoundation. It's one of the CF-Collections types which does *not* ship with a NS counterpart, but it can be wrapped in an objc class quickly, if desired.