# Attempt to insert nil

Tags: cocoa, boolean, nsmutablearray

Seems like it should be easy to add a boolean to an NSMutableArray.

Assume toDoArray is intialized as an NSMutableArray. The following:

```
BOOL checkBoxState = NO;
[toDoArray addObject:checkBoxState];
```

Generates the error "attempt to insert nil."

What's the correct way to add a negative boolean to a mutable array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSMutable arrays require an id, a weird part of Objective C. An id is any object, but not a primitive (For example, `int`s are primitives, while `NSArray`s are objects, and in extension, `id`s).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628343/objective-c-boolean-array) might help.

Comment: Nothing weird about `id`.  Objective-C doesn't have a fixed root class and, thus, `id` exists as a reference to an instance of any class.

Comment: I guess it's just me that finds it weird then.

Answer (score 6):

As others have said, `NSMutableArray` can only contain Objective-C objects.   They do not have to be subclasses of `NSObject`, but that is the most typical.

However, long before you ever see the `attempt to insert nil.` runtime error, you should have seen a compiler warning:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'addObject:' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

It is [in a vague and roundabout way] telling you exactly what the problem is;  you are trying to stick something into an array that is not a pointer [to an object].

Pay attention to warnings and fix them.  Most of the time, the presence of a warning will indicate a runtime error or crash.

Answer (score 0):

You need using NSNumber to wrap any primitive types (BOOL, int, NSInterger, etc.) before placing it inside collection object (NSArray, NSDictionary, etc.).

**Add BOOL to array:**

```
BOOL checkBoxState = NO;
NSNumber* n = [NSNumber numberWithBool:checkBoxState];
[toDoArray addObject:n];
```

**Get BOOL from array:**

```
NSNumber* n = [toDoArray objectAtIndex:0];
BOOL checkBoxState = [n boolValue];
```