# Warning when I fill an array with BOOL

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, boolean

I have this code:

```
BOOL booleanValue = TRUE;
[arrayZone replaceObjectAtIndex:indexZone withObject:booleanValue];
```

This code gives me a warning that says:

```
incompatible integer to pointer conversion: 
sending BOOL to parameter of type 'id'
```

Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to box your `BOOL` with a `NSNUmber` like this:

```
BOOL booleanValue = TRUE;
[arrayZone replaceObjectAtIndex:indexZone withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:booleanValue]];
```

Then, to retrieve your `BOOL` value, you unbox it using `boolValue`:

```
BOOL b = [[arrayZone objectAtIndex:index] boolValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only store objects within an `NSArray`, not basic types.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be a duplicate of [Objective C Boolean Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628343/objective-c-boolean-array)

In essence, BOOL is a primitive type - you have to wrap it in an Object to get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 0):

BOOL is a primitive type and your array requires an object. That's why you need to wrap it up in a NSNumber. But with newer xcode you can just type @YES or @NO and xcode will treat it like a numberWithBool.
So, instead of:

```
    BOOL booleanValue = TRUE;
    [arrayZone replaceObjectAtIndex:indexZone withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:booleanValue]];
```

you can now use

```
    [arrayZone replaceObjectAtIndex:indexZone withObject:@YES];
```