# didSelectItemAtIndexPath / didDeselectItemAtIndexPath in PSTCollectionView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, pstcollectionview

I'm working with `UICollectionView` using `PSTCollectionView`
Library. I've to create a grid where user can select and deselect
images by tapping on `UICollectionViewCell`. I've to show checkBox like
image if cell is selected. And uncheckedBox image if cell is
deselected. I am able to select `cell` and display checkBox image.And
also can deselect. But when I select next `cell`, the previous deselected
`cell` also get selected and shows checkBox image. This is the method I declared in `UICollectionViewCell` subClass

```
 -(void)applySelection{
    if(_isSelected){
        _isSelected=FALSE;
        self.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        self.selectImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked_edit_image.png"];
    }else{
        _isSelected=TRUE;
        self.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        self.selectImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_edit_image.png"];
    }
}
```

And here is my code for `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and
`didDeselectItemAtIndexPath`

```
- (void)collectionView:(PSTCollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"didSelect method called");
    FriendImageCell *cell = (FriendImageCell*)[imageGrid cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [selectedImages addObject:[[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] objectForKey:@"thumbnail_path_150_150"]];
         [cell applySelection];

}

- (void)collectionView:(PSTCollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"did deselect called");
    FriendImageCell *cell = (FriendImageCell*)[imageGrid cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [selectedImages removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    [cell setSelected:NO];
    [cell applySelection];
}
```

Can anyone please make me understand whats wrong with my code ? Make
me correct if I'm doing anything wrong. Tried many answers on
stack-overflow but nothing worked. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your `indexPath.item`? I cannot find it in the [NSIndexPath  reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/).

Comment: In `UICollectionView`, cell is considered as item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of back and forth discussion. I think I finally understand what your problem really is. You must have forgotten to set the `allowsMultipleSelection` to `YES`. So whenever a new cell is selected, your previous cells got deselected.

**allowsMultipleSelection**

> This property controls whether multiple items can be selected simultaneously. The default value of this property is NO.

And in my previous answer, I also suggested you to make your own boolean array to keep track of the selected items. However, I just realized that you don't have to. `indexPathsForSelectedItems` gives you an array of selected index paths.

**indexPathsForSelectedItems**

> An array of NSIndexPath objects, each of which corresponds to a single selected item. If there are no selected items, this method returns an empty array.

As a matter of fact, you don't even have to implement the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, and `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath`. By default, these two delegate methods will call `setSelected:` for you. Therefore, a more appropriate way to do is move your `applySelection` code in to `setSelected`.

Overwrite the `setSelected:` method in your custom `UICollectionViewCell`.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    [super setSelected:selected];

    // Change your UI
    if(_isSelected){
        self.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        self.selectImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked_edit_image.png"];
    }else{
        self.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        self.selectImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_edit_image.png"];
    }
}
```

Comment: How to create a array of boolean?

Comment: Yay, I just want to say it is a array of boolean. Let me just add "How to create a array of boolean?" to the answer, its a bit length to explain in comments..

Comment: Or maybe you can refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628343/objective-c-boolean-array

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't allow multiple cell selection.

Comment: It does, that's what we use for our app

Comment: I understand, But the problem is When I select a cell ,then select next cell,It deselects the previous one and image gets changed.

Comment: Yes, of cause a previous cell will get deselected. That why u cannot rely on cell default selected property for ur purposes. You on need to define your own datasource. An array of Boolean. U not even trying are u?

Comment: @Sushil, sorry that i may have led you the wrong way in my previous answer. I made a huge modification to it. This should adjust your issue now.

Comment: Thanks @yuchen, Actually I was using wrong variable of PSUICollectionView to allowMultipleSelection. Choosing the right variable solved the issue. Thanks.